# Работа с огромным массивом

Tags: json, node.js

Есть json массив большого размера(порядка 30000 записей(база товаров)), нужно разбить этот массив на части по 100 записей из этих записей сформировать лист-запрос и отправить его через POST запрос.

Отправить нужно всё содержимое массива, кусками по 100 записей.

Почему именно по 100? Потому что POST отправляется на API маркета, которое имеет ограничение на 100 товаров за один запрос.

Нужно: Разбить массив на части по 100 элементов и последовательно отправить POST запросом, при этом желательно не использовать сторонние библиотеки, максимум "Promise"

Comment: Первое что приходит в голову - взять и разбить ...

Comment: А в чем именно вопрос? как разбить? или как отправить кусочки последовательно? или что?

Comment: @Grundy, И как разбить и как отправить их последовательно и при этом желательно не использовать сторонние библиотеки, максимум "Promise"

Comment: @Бесенок стоит добавить это в вопрос.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для разделения массива на чанки, можно использовать нативный js или например [lodash chunk](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#chunk).

Затем можно использовать возможности `async/await` или например [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)

Это небольшой пример с `for` и `await`:

```
// * node.js 8
// const axios = require('axios')
const products = require('./products.json')

async function main(data) {
  data = data || []

  let i, j, chunk = 100
  for (i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i += chunk) {
    await apiQuery(data.slice(i, i + chunk))
  }

  console.log('*** DONE ***')
}

function apiQuery(data) {
  console.log(`query for next ${data.length} records`)
  // axios.post(...)
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(resolve, 100)
  })
}

// start
main(products)
```

Comment: если количество не будет кратно chunk, то последние элементы отбросятся

Comment: нет, будет столько, сколько осталось в главном в массиве

Comment: логично, с временем увеличения `i` ошибся

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, но не хотелось бы использовать сторонние библиотеки

Comment: @Бесенок, в приведенном коде не использованы сторонние библиотеки, по крайней мере в раскомментированной части.

Comment: Думаю, что сила современных систем именно в дополнительных пакетах/библиотеках, без них рутина и хаос будут просто немыслимых масштабов, а скорость разработки упадет в разы или порядки) В рамках теста, собеседования или изучения языка, да это оправданно, но в реальном приложении НЕТ. Пакеты проходят тесты, обновляются и предоставляют удобный API. Со временем функционал части пакетов становиться основой для стандарта языка.

Comment: Дело было в том, что у меня была старая версия node (6.11.~) из за этого на async выбивало ошибку и в следствии чего я и подумал что используется сторонняя библиотека async.

Comment: @diproart, Спасибо за помощь, переделал ваш код под себя и получил то, что и требовалось.
Почему именно `for (i = 0, j = data.length; i < j; i += chunk) `, а не
`for ( var i = 0; i < data.length; i += chunk )`? Разницы же нет.

Comment: Это одно из правил "правильного" JavaScript, в первом случае переменная `j ` определяется только один раз. Во втором "длина" массива вычисляется на каждой итерации.